# Proper subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is nowhere dense.

Tags: real-analysis, baire-category

How can we prove that if $V$ is proper subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, then $V$ is nowhere dense. My try:

I will prove that any open ball $B(x,r)$ will not be contained in $V$. By contradiction, suppose that $B(x,r) \subset V$, then $B(0,r) = -x + B(x,r) \subset V$.

Therefore, $~~\mathbb{R}^{n} = \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}n B(0,r) \subset V$.
Which implies $\mathbb{R}^{n} = V$ a contradiction to given hypothesis.

Is this proof correct or there is some flaw in arguments.

Comment: I think you're on the right track, but the argument doesn't quite check out, since $B(x,r)\subset V$ does not imply that $-x+B(x,r)\subset V$. Here's a hint (which you may need to prove on its own as a lemma): for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $\mathbb{R}^n=\cup_{m\in\mathbb{N}} B(x,m)$. I'm not sure which form of the Baire Category Theorem you want to use here.

Comment: Edited my question. Can't we use the property of subspace to prove that $B(0,r) \subset V.$

Comment: No -- or at least it doesn't follow immediately (or from the current argument).

Comment: Can you please help me to complete argument.

Comment: What are you allowed to assume? For instance, the result is immediate if you are able to assert the existence of a point whose distance from every point in the subspace is greater than some given positive number (e.g. any point not in the subspace that lies on a line that is perpendicular to that subspace).